# Remove Number with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to remove number at beginning and the end of word in one sentence for example:

> "123helo helo123"

then it will return

> "helo helo"

I've tried this pattern:

`/^[0-9]|[0-9]$/`

but it just recognized them as one string but not in words. Can you help me?

Comment: To remove all numbers just use /\d+/ instead

Comment: try grouping the two parts you are OR'ing with brackets like so /(^[0-9])|([0-9]$)/

Comment: JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: *"beginning and the end **of word**"* ~ this caught my attention. What should happen for "123helo 123helo"?

Comment: Same as removing leading/trailing whitespace. replace the space with the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, including specifically where you mention *"at beginning and the end **of word**"*, this should suffice

```
str.replace(/\b\d+|\d+\b/g, '')
```

`\b` is the [word-boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) character. The above removes all numbers directly after or directly before a word-boundary.

Comment: new to gerexs what is the `|` in between doing ?

Comment: Think of it like "or".

Answer (score 0):

Try `/^\d*(.*)\d*$/` and match capture group 1.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression) to see how to use capture groups.

Comment: Use `\d+` instead of `\d*` if you want to exclude the possibility that a number is omitted.

Comment: This removes the digits at the beginning and end of the sentence (string), not each word.

Answer (score 0):

PHP solution:

```
$string = '123helo helo123';
$result = preg_replace('/^\d+|\d+$/', '', $string);
echo $result; // helo helo
```

Javascript solution:

```
var string = '123helo helo123';
var result = string.replace(/^\d+|\d+$/g, '');
console.log(result); // helo helo
```

Or this RegExp for triming each word in `123hello hello123 123hello`

```
/\b\d+|\d+\b/
```

Comment: thank you for your help :) but what if I modified the string to 'abc 123helo helo123 abc' ? I was so curious

Comment: @brownie `'abc 123helo helo123 abc'.replace(/\b\d+|\d+\b/g,'')` will return `abc helo helo abc` in JavaScript.